# Is this a proper way to find the derivate of a 12-bit ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, noise, formula-derivation

I'm seeking a solution to find the derivative of an 12-bit ADC. It's for STM32 but let's say it's for likely for an arbitrary micro controller.

```
while(1){

  uint16_t a1 = adc(0); // Read the analog value first time

  uint32_t t1 = time(); // Get the time

  uint16_t a2 = adc(0); // Read the analog value second time

  uint32_t delta = time() - t1; // Update the time difference

  uint16_t d = (a2-a1)/(delta); // Find the derivative of adc(0)

}
```

Are they any better solutions rather than this solution if I'm using FreeRTOS?

What if I have noise in my measurements? What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: The word you are looking for is *differentiate*, not derivate. You differentiate something to get its derivative.

Comment: @DKNguyen oH! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the concept looks basically correct but there are a couple of issues.

Unless your sampling time is variable, you should not need to read the time. You should already know the sampling interval beforehand

If the sampling time is variable, you need to record the time associated with when the actual sample was taken. Your current code doesn't do that. It records the time completely independently of the sample some time after the sample has already been taken. If you are behind an RTOS there is probably a much better way to do it like setting the ADC to automatically sample and automatically writie the samples into a buffer so you can read the samples and differentiate whenever you want knowing that the interval time is constant.

Yes, noise will be an issue. You want to filter the ADC readings before differentiating since it is very sensitive to noise. Even a small magnitude change over a small time interval (such as when sampling at a very high frequency) results in enormous slopes that may completely swamp your graph. I've found the easiest way to deal with this is to actually reduce the sampling rate which reduces the slope of the line between adjacent samples.

Comment: So you mean, only take the difference, will giving me a good derivative (change) ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson No. He's saying that the time is/should be fixed, so it's a constant in the denominator. No need to call a function to read the time and calculate the elapsed time.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson If you want to know the real slope, you still need to divide by the sampling interval. I'm just saying if you know your sampling interval is constant then you don't need to read the time each time. You just directly divide by the sampling time. If I know I am sampling every 1 millisecond, I don't need to record the time after each sample, and subtract them to get 1ms. I already know what the time interval will be.

Comment: @Aaron In this case, time is not fixed. I'm using RTOS.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Then you do need to sample the time but that time has to be associated with the time the sample was taken. Your code looks like the time will be measured sometime after and completely independently of the sample which will be inaccurate. There's probably a better way buried in there somewhere where you can set the ADC directly and read samples from it as they come in in a buffer or something.

Comment: If trying to control anything with this derivative, you'll find constant sample rate MUCH easier to tune.

Comment: You say "time is not fixed, I'm using an RTOS" as if using an RTOS makes time not be fixed.  Your best bet is to trigger ADC reads from a timer so that they *will* be fixed -- an RTOS certainly doesn't get in the way of that, and in some ways facilitates it.

Answer (score 1):

The RTOS and timing catches having been discussed by others, the numerical differentiation greatly amplifies [quantization noise](https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/slides-types_of_noise_in_adcs_0_0.pdf) for medium- and low-changing signals. Depending on a nature of signals under consideration, there exist well established numerical techniques to deal with this amplification: oversampling, interpolation, Kalman filtering etc.

An [article on an oversampling technique application](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3297130/) compares a dependence of quantization noise amplification on signal change rate in Figure 2 (see below).

[image]

> (a) Piecewise quadratic acceleration profile. (b) Theoretical and
> finite-difference derivatives.][1](https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/slides-types_of_noise_in_adcs_0_0.pdf)

You may see patterns relevant to your observation. If this is the case, you can try oversampling. But don't forget about other techniques!

Answer (score 1):

Others talked about the timing issues, so I will focus on removing the noise from the measurements as it could be large. Basic principle is to approximate a derivative with more points than two. One of the simplest technique is called [five point stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil) which can be easily used on most MCUs. It uses 4 points to calculate the first derivative as:
$$f'(x)\approx\frac{-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{12h}$$
Where f(x) are the ADC readings and h is the time difference between two readings. This technique can be generalized with [finite difference coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient). Another possibility would be to filter your ADC samples before calculating the derivative, for example with [Gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter).